# How imageJ call IJ_Props.txt file?

Tags: java, imagej

Recently I am learning imageJ codes. I found IJ-Props.txt file is very important for many internal plugins. Without, many plugins in submanu disappear.  I would like to know how imageJ calls and uses this text file. Please give me your idea. Thank you!

William

Answer (score 0):

Doing a [*grep* search on the ImageJ git repository](http://fiji.sc/git/?p=ImageJA.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=IJ_Props.txt), I found that the file `IJ_Props.txt` is loaded within the [`ij.Prefs` class](http://fiji.sc/git/?p=ImageJA.git;a=blob;f=src/main/java/ij/Prefs.java#l158).

If you look into the file ([`IJ_Props.txt`](http://fiji.sc/git/?p=ImageJA.git;a=blob;f=src/main/resources/IJ_Props.txt)), you'll find in the comments that the properties are loaded from the resource file within `ij.jar`, which you can inspect by opening it with a ZIP utility.